# Why doesn't "this" keyword work with static methods in a class in my code below?

Tags: javascript, static, this

I'm doing the exercise from [Eloquent's JavaScript: Exercise Section -> Groups](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html). I managed to code okay, but I don't understand why my code doesn't work when I use `this`.

My current code:

```
class Group {
  constructor() {
    this.members = [];
  }

  has(value) {
    return this.members.includes(value);
  }

  add(value) {
    if (!this.has(value)) this.members.push(value);
  }

  delete(value) {
    if (this.has(value)) return this.members =
      this.members.filter(element => element != value);
  }

  static from(array) {
    let newGroup = new Group();
    for (let element of array) {
      newGroup.add(element);
    }
    return newGroup;
  }
}
```

I tried changing `static from(array) {...}` to:

```
static from(array) {
  let newGroup = new Group();
  for (let element of array) {
    this.members.push(element);
  }
  return newGroup;
}
```

Considering that `newGroup.add(element)` and `this.members.push(element)` are relatively the same, why doesn't the latter work in the second static method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Considering that newGroup.add(element) and this.members.push(element)

Nope. `this` inside a static method points to the class itself (`Group`), it does not point to a non existing instance. That means you could use it as:

```
 let newGroup = new this();
 newGroup.members.push(element);
```

Comment: I see. So it doesn't point to `newGroup` then. Thank you for the explanation :-)!